# Searching a Value in Json Array

Tags: java, json, parsing

i have the following json response:

```
{
"elements":
[
    {
        "id": "1234",
        "Key": "1234-name2",  
         "name": "name2",
        "projectName": "TestProject",      
    },
    {
        "id": "5678",
        "applicationKey": "5678-name2",
        "name": "name2",
        "projectName": "TestProject2",
    },
   {
        "id": "9101112",
        "applicationKey": "9101112-name3",
        "name": "name3",
        "projectName": "TestProject3",
    },
],
"totalSize": 3
}
```

After getting the response, i have converted it to a string:

```
    String PaListContent = getContent(PaListResponse);

    private static String getContent(HttpResponse response) {
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity == null) return null;
        BufferedReader reader;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent()));
            String line = reader.readLine();
            reader.close();
            return line;
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Now, i want to search a projectname (e.g. "Testproject2") in the String and want to have the attributes "id" and "name" as well.

i have tried it with

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(PaListContent);
JSONObject myResponse = jsonObject.getJSONObject("elements");
//JSONArray tsmresponse = (JSONArray) myResponse.get("listTsm");

ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

for(int i=0; i<tsmresponse.length(); i++){
    list.add(tsmresponse.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
}

System.out.println(list);
```

But the problem is, that i always get "org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONArray". I think the problem is, because my json is an array, but how can i get the attributes?

Best Regards!

Comment: Try `System.out.println(jsonObject)` to see what it really contains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `elements` is a JSONArray, but you are trying to parse it as a JSONObject, change your code like this:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(PaListContent);
JSONArray myResponse = jsonObject.getJSONArray("elements");
//JSONArray tsmresponse = (JSONArray) myResponse.get("listTsm");

ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

for(int i=0; i<myResponse.length(); i++){
    list.add(myResponse.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
}

System.out.println(list);
```

This will work as expected

Comment: It wasn't me, but the type of `myResponse` should be `JSONArray` no?

Comment: Yes corrected, I was editing due to network issues it got delayed, by the time someone downvoted !

Answer (score 0):

> But the problem is, that i always get **`org.json.simple.JSONObject` cannot be cast `to org.json.simple.JSONArray`**. I think the problem is, because my json is an array, but **how can i get the attributes?**

use `JSONArray` instead

```
JSONArray myResponse = jsonObject.getJSONArray("elements");
```

[Here](https://processing.org/reference/JSONObject_getJSONArray_.html) you can find further examples

Comment: @InfoEngi glad to hear, if you solved it, you can click the checkmark **`V`**  to mark the answer as accepted http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work